# retrieving all related rows via foreign key before deletion

Tags: mysql

I have a table **A**, Many other tables have foreign keys which cascade on delete. Is there anyway to get all the deleted rows before, using

> delete from A where id = 1

. Basically What I want is to know which rows from other tables are getting deleted.

I don't want to hard code to other tables, as we might add more tables later on, and I do not want to keep updating the query every time a new table is added.

We might even have more connection like table **B** have foreign key in **A**, and table **C** might have a foreign key in table **B**

Comment: You may perform this action using stored procedure with dynamic SQL, which retrieves all FK dependencies from INFORMATION_SCHEMA and get all dependent records... alternatively you may open transaction, gather the info about all records in potentially dependent tables, delete the row in question, compare another tables states and get identifying info about dissapeared records, then rollback... but I'm not sure that it is easy in both variants.

Comment: FKs have a limited set of capabilities; you are asking to go beyond that they can provide.